# Attributes.add, ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript, ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a button on a webform, inside an update panel that is inside an Ajax Toolkit tabcontainer, that saves data in the textboxes to the database. I have five `if` statements that validate date ranges on the page and put up an alert if the ranges are invalid using (for example):

```
If <condition> Then
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Actual end date cannot be earlier than Sign date.');", True)
    updateFlag = False
End If
```

This code works fine. A flag is set for updating the data. The problem is if the code falls through the `if` into the update section: the `alert` I put there saying "Data saved" doesn't pop up after the updates are done. I've used each of the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Job saved.');", True)
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Job saved.');", True)
Me.btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('Job saved.');")
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() 'don't have the rest of this line
```

None of them have worked. The data is saved as it should be; it's as if the code jumps over the `alert` line. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

Edit: clarifying that I put `Me.btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('Job saved.');")` in the Page_Load as well as after the update statements, but that one fires before the data is actually saved, so that error messages are received after the data is "saved". Wrong order, can't use it.

Edit 2: Posting more code. Code behind:

```
Protected Sub SaveAll()
    If <condition> Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Actual end date cannot be earlier than Sign date.');", True)
        updateFlag = False
    End If
    ...
    If updateFlag Then
        'add values to SqlDataAdapter
        ...
        con.Open()
        da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        da.Dispose()
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Job saved.');", True)
        'ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Job saved.');", True)
        'Me.btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('Job saved.');")
        Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx?ID=" & txtID.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

aspx:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" 
    runat="server" TabStripPlacement="Top">
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="JobPanel" HeaderText="Job Info">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" OnClick="SaveAll" 
                runat="server" Text="Save" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Please let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Do you get a client side error? If you debug on the server, does it successfully call `RegisterStartupScript()`?

Comment: I don't get an error. If I walk through the code, it does stop on that line, but nothing happens.

Comment: If you view the source HTML through your browser after hitting the button, do you see at the bottom where it injects the JavaScript?

Comment: Then you need to post more code in your question, as your question is [not complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well there's your problem. You have an UpdatePanel. Never use UpdatePanel. They're evil. And if you do use, always say so in a question. And if you have problems on a page that has one, get rid of it and see if it works. Using AJAX directly is much *much* better.

Comment: I actually did say that it's on an update panel from the start. But thank you  for your comment, I wish I knew how to do this with Ajax. I've got more controls on the panel (omitted for being irrelevant), can I use them like you recommend for the scripts? Or should I try moving just the buttons outside the update panel? And should I ask a new question if that doesn't work?

Comment: Ah, so you did. Still, I would have bolded that. Make it really obvious. Having an UpdatePanel is like going to work with Ebola. You don't just tell people you're sick. You give everyone a big warning. I would *get rid of* the UpdatePanel, and do everything with AJAX. What version of .NET are you on? And sticking with this question is fine for the moment.

Comment: I will remember that. I have updatepanels on most of the aspx pages, mostly because of answers to other questions I've read here. In another question of mine that deals with two cascading dropdowns and one autocomplete field, I had read that they need to be on updatepanels. I'm actually reading a whitepaper on that now. I'm just not familiar enough with this yet. I'll let you know what I come up with. Thanks!

Comment: The built in cascading drop downs need update panels to not behave all squirrely, but that's a good reason not to use them too. Go with plain AJAX. The programming is simpler, it's less work for the client and server, and uses less bandwidth. This particular case doesn't need AJAX though. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an UpdatePanel or even AJAX in this particular scenario.

```
Protected Sub SaveAll()
    If <condition> Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Actual end date cannot be earlier than Sign date.');", True)
        updateFlag = False
    End If
    ...
    If updateFlag Then
        'add values to SqlDataAdapter
        ...
        con.Open()
        da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        da.Dispose()
        Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx?ID=" & txtID.Text & "&message=Job%20Saved")
    End If
End Sub
```

You were trying to run some client side script, but then you were redirecting which ends the response. The solution therefore is to pass the message to the next page, and have the next page display the confirmation message. The `Edit.aspx` page should check the query string on page load for a message, then display it if there is one. But don't use `alert()`. Those suck. They grab the users attention and can't be styled. Find a nice client side notification library. I really like [noty](http://ned.im/noty/).

I'm not a VB programmer, but you need to wrap your database connections in a `using` statement so they properly dispose (or whatever the VB equivalent is).

Comment: I have downloaded noty and I'm working on making my own little noties now. I took the buttons out of the updatepanel, keeping them on the tabpanel, and I reworked response.redirect so that it passes the message. I check for the message in prerender and pop up that messagebox if it exists. Thanks!